# I am having an issue understanding how to work with queues

Tags: c++

below is one of my professors slides for my Data structures class and I have been doing research and cannot figure out the concepts here and I have to build a program with this in my data structures class.

What does .back do?  what are we sending into the actual functions below:
Please explain like i am a 6 year old...

ADT-Queue (tool kit functions Array implementation)

```
//Create a q.
void create_queue(Queue & q)
{
    q.back = -1;
}

//check if Queue is empty
int empty( const QUEUE & q)
{
    return (q.back == -1);
}

//Purge elements in the queue
void purge(Queue & q)
{
    q.back = -1;
}

//Add an element on the q.
void enq(Queue & q, CONST INFOREC & item)
{
    ++ q.back;
q.i[q.back] = item; // i is an array of ints previously declared
}

// delete an item from the q
void deq(Queue &q, INFOREC & item)
{
    int ct; 
    item =q.i[0]; front;
    // step forward loop, moving the entire array components 1 place forward and
    // shifting the pointers
    for (ct = 1; ct < q.back; ++ct);
    q.i[ct -1] = q.i [ct];  
    --q.back;
 }
```

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly?

Comment: You seem to have some comments in that code that aren't marked as such...also some case issues: are `QUEUE` and `Queue` supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: Do you have more code samples and/or slides?

Comment: Okay, yep, that's the code we needed to see. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my guess is that the ADT is designed in such a way that the Queue always points to the first element added and `back` is always -1 when there are no elements in the queue.

Check the `create_queue`, a new queue is created and no elements are enqued yet and thus initialize `back` to -1

Similarly `empty`, if no elements are present `back` will be still -1

In `purge`, all the elements are removed and thus the `back` needs to be updated to -1

So if there was a function named `enqueue` .. `back` will be updated to a value which is **not** -1

P.S:- This is a wild guess as we cannot predict until we see the complete code :)

*EDIT***
As per the updated code what I have suggested works fine, back will be -1 if queue is empty... else its an array pointing from 0 to n-1(max_queue_size) ... 0 --> first element

Comment: Is this the rest of the code you need?  it is the previous slide.  Sorry I just realized it now...

Comment: 'typedef int INFOREC;
           Struct QUEUE {
                          INFOREC i[30];
                              int back;
                              };
                  QUEUE q;
                  //q.back is 5the location or the subscript'

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to reflect new information given in the question.

`back` is a pointer to the last element in the queue, that is, the most recently added element.

Together with `i`, this is all the queue needs to maintain its internal data structure. Since `i` is statically allocated and elements are only ever indexed using `back`, it is unnecessary to explicitly delete elements from the queue; this is why no change is necessary to `i` within `purge()`. If you add elements, `purge()` or `deq()` them, and then add more elements, the new elements simply overwrite the previous elements in memory, which is exactly what you want; and since `back` is adjusted appropriately within each of these methods, it's impossible to access data members that are no longer logically in the queue, even though they still exist in system memory.

Note that the "de" in `deq` doesn't stand for "delete"; `deq` is short for "dequeue," which is the standard term for retrieving the oldest element from the queue. The corresponding term for adding an element to the back of the queue is "enqueue."

Comment: I assumed it only because it's called `back` and not `front`. I realize there was nothing in the logic to indicate that, though.

Comment: (There is now, though, obviously.)

Answer (score 1):

The front of the queue is at 0, the back is at q.back, so the q.back is initialized to -1 when the queue is empty.

Check if queue is empty should return true when back is -1, else false:

```
bool empty(const Queue & q)
{
    return (q.back == -1);
}
```

purge makes the queue empty again, so is the same as init.

Comment: why do we always subtract 1 to signify it is the beginning of the array or "0"     What are we subtracting 1 from?